# In emacs dired mode, is there a setting that dired uses eshell-ls and other eshell commands?

Tags: emacs, dired, eshell

This answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28981/finding-files-by-names mentions

"If you are running Dired with a 'ls' implemented in elisp, 'ls-lisp' or 'eshell-ls', then you can recursively list all the files matching a wildcard".

But I do not know how to achieve that.

Is there a way (customization or setting in init.el) to ask dired to use eshell commands where available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ls-lisp` emulation (`ls-lisp.el`), which is part of vanilla Emacs. (Someone else will hopefully answer for eshell.)

To enable `ls-lisp`, customize option `ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program` to the value `nil`.

See the Emacs manual, node [ls in Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/ls-in-Lisp.html).

See also Emacs Wiki page [ls Lisp](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LsLisp).

Comment: I am accepting your solution as it showed me the path.

Answer (score 1):

[Drew's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729907/drew) answer showed me the path. Looking through eshell variables, it looks like to enable `eshell-ls` in lisp, we can use `eshell-ls-use-in-dired` to 't:

(setq eshell-ls-use-in-dired 't)